# PHP how to encode binary data to base 64

Tags: php, base64

I am using PHP openssl_sign to create a digital signature using the tutorial [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php). How can i convert $signature (which contains binary data) to Base64.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert binary to base64 using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Answer (score 6):

Just do:

```
base64_encode($signature);
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php